# Issue with Purchase Requisition Module - OpenErp

Tags: python, module, odoo

I got this error when i click on "Confirm Requisition" button in the module "Purchase Requisition"

```
 File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server\openerp\addons\purchase_requisition\purchase_requisition.py", line 215, in wkf_confirm_order AttributeError: 'purchase.order' object has no attribute 'signal_purchase_cancel'
```

The error code in 'purchase_requisition.py' is as follows:

```
class purchase_order(osv.osv):
_inherit = "purchase.order"
_columns = {
    'requisition_id' : fields.many2one('purchase.requisition','Purchase Requisition')
}

def wkf_confirm_order(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None ):
    res = super(purchase_order, self).wkf_confirm_order(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
    proc_obj = self.pool.get('procurement.order')
    for po in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        if po.requisition_id and (po.requisition_id.exclusive=='exclusive'):
            for order in po.requisition_id.purchase_ids:
                if order.id != po.id:
                    proc_ids = proc_obj.search(cr, uid, [('purchase_id', '=', order.id)])
                    if proc_ids and po.state=='confirmed':
                        proc_obj.write(cr, uid, proc_ids, {'purchase_id': po.id})
                    self.signal_purchase_cancel(cr, uid, [order.id])
                po.requisition_id.tender_done(context=context)
    return res 
purchase_order()
```

I did not develop this module, so what could be the cause of this error?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you check you have latest code?

Comment: Yes, well the latest on apps.openerp.com

Comment: But it happens only when i "Confirm order" on Quotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have not latest code.

In my local the code are like this:

```
class purchase_order(osv.osv):
    _inherit = "purchase.order"
    _columns = {
        'requisition_id' : fields.many2one('purchase.requisition','Purchase Requisition')
    }
    def wkf_confirm_order(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        res = super(purchase_order, self).wkf_confirm_order(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
        proc_obj = self.pool.get('procurement.order')
        for po in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            if po.requisition_id and (po.requisition_id.exclusive=='exclusive'):
                for order in po.requisition_id.purchase_ids:
                    if order.id<>po.id:
                        proc_ids = proc_obj.search(cr, uid, [('purchase_id', '=', order.id)])
                        if proc_ids and po.state=='confirmed':
                            proc_obj.write(cr, uid, proc_ids, {'purchase_id': po.id})
                        wf_service = netsvc.LocalService("workflow")
                        wf_service.trg_validate(uid, 'purchase.order', order.id, 'purchase_cancel', cr)
                    po.requisition_id.tender_done(context=context)
        return res
```

Comment: Where do you got this one? Launchpad?

Comment: I replaced the class with this code, but it gives me another error, think i'm gooing to fully upgrade the module, but the one i've downloaded it's the latest on apps.openerp.com

Comment: Here is link for 6.1 and 7.0 addons  https://code.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/6.1  and https://code.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/7.0

Comment: Well, i can't find it, i mean the one i find it's the same i have, updated on 05/04/2013 [purchasereq](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/trunk/view/head:/purchase_requisition/purchase_requisition.py) Oh - Ok let me check

Comment: OOk, found it :), but your version says modified on 2012-12-20 11:47:30 UTC - older than the other one lol, i'll download it and try it, thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok, the codes you provide are correct, must say they aren't the latest ones, and in folder /wizard i replaced the 'purchase_requisition_partner' with the real latest one (The original package that gave me the error) Thank you very much!